# Mongo / Mongoose special character query not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, utf-8, bson

I need help with mongo. Im unable to query my value. Im using online atlas tool for debugging and even atlas is unable to query it.

In my collection this value stored as `(っ◔◡◔)っ ♥  ♥`
If im trying to query it just with CTRL+C and CTRL+V into my query, its doesnt work.

My query is: `{originalSender: {$regex: "(っ◔◡◔)っ ♥  ♥", $options: "gi"}}`

If im removing some characters from query and its stays only at `{originalSender: {$regex: "(っ◔◡◔)", $options: "gi"}}`, its working. But if im adding one more `っ`, its break again.
Query working if there only `♥` too.

Im tested this with other part of string, query is saying there 0 results.
Im attaching some screenshots in case if my problem is not clear.

[image: Doesnt work] [image: working with removed only one symbol]
[image: Chat codes stored in collection]

So my question is: Is it my misstake or this is a bug? Is there any ways to fix that or workarounds?
Thanks!

Comment: For instance, `` is **U+1D49F** _MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL D_ but you see (unprintable) surrogate pair instead `0xd835,0xdc9f` (== `55349,56479`).

Comment: But its breaks arleady at second `っ`, which is just a copy of first symbol, which working fine. This is very strange. How may it affect other symbol?

Comment: BTW: [The `$regex` operator does not support the global search modifier `g`.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)